# Cannot click on game window in Python

Tags: python, html

I was trying to make a bot for a game, which you can find [here](https://rollercoin.com). You have to play games to get a tiny amount of bitcoin, like satoshis. Anyway, I as going to make a bot, but when I tried to click on the game window, it didn't do anything. Here is my code:
clicker.py

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.click(x, y, button='left')
```

I don't know what's going on, is it my code, or is it the website  html? If it is the html, what should i change?

Comment: print all actions and tell us what gets printed

Comment: Hello, prune. I believe that my code above can be pasted into a file and ran.

Comment: Also, when the game pops up, there is a 'start' button, but when i inspect element, it only shows up as one html block. How can I click on the start button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What may be happening is that when you run the program, your mouse clicks so fast that the site does not recognize the clicks. But anyways, how the program is supposed to stop? Your mouse will be clicking everywhere and you may not be able to close the Python window. Do something like this:

```py
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def click_function():
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        pyautogui.click(x, y, button='left')
        sleep(0.5)  # an acceptable waiting time between one click and another

t = Thread(target=click_function)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
sleep(60)
# Here you put the amount of time you want the program
# to run, in seconds. This will ensure that the program
# stops sometime and you don't get stuck.
```

You can try adding `sleep(n)` at the beginning of the code. That is, you run the program, enter the site normally and point your mouse at the specific part where you want to click. Change the value of `n` to a considerable amount of time in seconds you can perform these tasks. If this doesn't work, you can try the [Pynput module](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/), which works similarly to PyAutoGUI.

Comment: I think there is a way to block automation in html, but you have to see, I tried your code, but it still didn't work. Go to the link in the message above, and test it out for yourself.